# is both codes have the same meaning?

Tags: java, android, listadapter

currently i'm studying the setListAdapter, and have come across 2 snippets of code below.

Snippet 1:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_nm, R.id.layout_idnm, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Snippet 2:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_nm, R.id.layout_idnm, items););
```

my question is:

1. do both snippets have the same meaning?
2. does the second snippet define ArrayAdapter?

Comment: yeah same. But the 1st one is a good practice. Because you can reuse the adapter without creating it again

Comment: Also this is not related to android, it is a general programming question.

Comment: thx & sorry i only learn C programming, not even C++ or java.
now only start self learning java.
this code is part of d android project i'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** There is an extra `";"` in the 2nd option, so remove it...

**Before:**

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_nm, R.id.layout_idnm, items););
```

**After:**

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_nm, R.id.layout_idnm, items));
```

**2.** If you are using the 2nd approach you are **NOT creating a local variable, this will create a problem when you will need to refer this ArrayList object again in the code.**

For example you will need this local variable if you want to do something like `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the two is that you've declared a local variable in the first one but not in the second.

Programatically it makes no difference but I personally think the first is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Both the code have **same meaning**.

Only a difference is that Code 1 is creating a separate adapter object (local variable and You can reuse it later) and Code 2 is setting adapter to your ListView directly.

Comment: It doesn't create a separate adapter object. The exact same number of adapter objects are created; the first example gives a name to the adapter where the second one does not.

Comment: @lain FYI, Code 1 will occupy memory by creating object.

Comment: Yaa...@PareshMayani is true...the basic OOP concept.

Comment: Not so. When you say `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_nm, R.id.layout_idnm, items)`, that creates the object. In the first case, you hold a reference to that object while also giving a reference to the object to setListAdapter (which will presumably hold onto the reference). In the second case, you just pass the reference straight on to setListAdapter. It's unlikely to make any difference in terms of memory: `adapter` is a local variable, so it will go out of scope at the end of the function invocation, whereas setListAdapter will hold on to the thing until the view goes away.

Comment: @lain..creating 5 objects of the same will not consume more memory?? It was only said that creating the Object consumes memory.

Comment: Sure, creating more objects will consume more memory. But the same number of objects is created in both cases: precisely one ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

**Only difference readability and  maintainability**

First is different and better because  the code has more readability and 
maintainability when needs to rebuild;